# How can I query out six-digit decimals full data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I query data using Apache IoTDB, it seems like by only two-digit decimals of data are queried out by default. The original data is in six-digit decimals. Anyone know how can I reset the default settings and query and retrieve the stored full data, which contains six-digit decimals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the MAX_POINT_NUMBER parameter of FLOAT and DOUBLE type of time series in Apache IoTDB if your encoding method is RLE or TS_2DIFF. This parameter is the number of digits you need after the floating point for the data exported.